# How to store string / integer value in Broadcast receiver.?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I have one receiver which extend Broadcast Receiver.I am passing string value from  main activity. when activity create it pass the value to receiver.I can receive that string value. But my problem is, I can not save that string values.

i have tried shared preference with context in Broadcast Receiver but it is not working.

My Receiver code is Here.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{


  if(intent.getAction().equals("my.action.string")){
         state = intent.getExtras().getString("value");

         Toast.makeText(context, "this is state : " + state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("state_lock", state);
                editor.commit();

            p = prefs.getString("state_type", state);
      Toast.makeText(context, "the state type is : "+ p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

With this code i can get only data but can not store them.

anyone can help me. How can I store data in Broadcast Receiver.?

thank you in advance.

Comment: once check your state is null or not before saving.

Comment: @nag when activity load data pass to receiver. at this time i can receive Toast as 1 but i can not store it.

Comment: @Nag second thing is i am using action screen on and off. so when screen goes to off or on the preference become null.

Comment: @Nag can i store data in Broadcast Receiver..?

Comment: No problem, you can store.

Comment: @Nag any other solution to store this values.?

Comment: Are you using these value in any other place other than reciever?

Comment: @Nag No i am using this only in this receiver.

Comment: Then what is the need of storing it somewhere directly use that state wherever you want in the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving data using `"stae_lock"` key value and getting data using `"state_type"` To get the value you stored previously use the same key like

```
 p = prefs.getString("state_lock", state);
```

Comment: @ chandrakantha i try this but still shared preference can not save data. its show null value.

Comment: Once check the value getting from intent extras is not null or not?

Comment: first time is not null but when this action  `if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"))` start to work the p become null. I can get value on activity create. but when above action start the value of p become null. Toast display null value

Answer (score 0):

```
p = prefs.getString("state_type", state);
```

instead of use following to get data

```
p = prefs.getString("state_lock", state);
```

Comment: @ balu i try this but still shared preference can not save data. its show null value.